# How to assign enum type arguement in scala

Tags: scala

```
object StorageType extends Enumeration{
    type Name = Value
    val HTML, TEXT, SUBJECT = Value
  }

def read(key:String, _type:StorageType.Value = StorageType.HTML):String = {
    val accessKey = getPrefix(_type) + key
    DaoFactory.getPreviewStorageDao.get(accessKey).data
  }
```

Does this mean I can only send StorageType.HTML as argument and not StorageType.SUBJECT?
Also I am pretty new to scala so can you tell me what exactly does _type do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_type` parameter can be any one of the `StorageType.Value` instances, but if you don't put any instance into it when you call the method, then the `StorageType.HTML` instance will be automatically assigned.